# Дефолтный url параметр ui-router

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, ui-router

Добавил локализацию.
Две локали (de и ru - по умолчанию).
Ссылки теперь выглядят так www.site/de или www.site/ru(www.site по умолчанию ru).
State выглядит так.

```
$stateProvider
            .state('shell', {
                url: '/{locale:(?:ru|de)}',
                params: {
                    locale: {squash: true, value: 'ru'}
                },
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/shell.html',
                controller: 'shellCtrl'
            }).state('shell.contacts', {
                url: '/contacts/',
                templateUrl: 'app/pages/contacts/contacts.html',
                controller: 'contactsCtrl'
            })
```

Например мы зашли на сайт по ссылке site/de и на странице есть ссылка

```
<a ui-sref="shell.contact()">Контакты</a>
```

Получится ссылка.

```
<a href="/contacts">Контакты</a>
```

При нажатии по ссылке мы перейдем на url www.site/contacts.
В таком случае locale теряется. Нам же нужно www.site/de/contacts.
Чтобы сохранить локаль нужно изменить shell.contacts() на shell.contacts({locale:'de'}). 
Вопрос, как автоматически подставлять в параметры url ту или иную локаль в зависимости от текущей не меняя всех ссылок на странице?

Comment: сохраняй текущее значение из параметров и используй его

Comment: @Grundy сохранить я могу, но как сделать чтобы locale оставался именно в url?

Answer (score -1):

Можно поменять урл уже после смены стейта.

getCurrentLocale в данном примере должен возвращать текущее значение locale. Хранить его можно любым удобным способом.

```
$rootScope.$on('$stateChangeSuccess', (event, toState, toParams, fromState, fromParams) => {
   toParams.locale = getCurrentLocale();
   $state.go(toState.name, toParams, {notify:false, reload: false});
});
```